looking for formula/function/VBA script, to automatically copy contents from a range of cells according to the selection of a Cell, within said range
Ex: In sheet 1, I have 4 columns containing customer and sales info, like: column a: names, column b:dates, column c: service, column d: amount.see image
And in sheet 2, I have an invoice template.see image
And when selecting needed cells, ex: in row 3 that has a name, date, service and amount I want it to automatically copy and fill the invoice template on sheet 2, in the related cells.
To continue, when selecting the following customer's info, ex: now in row 4, the template on sheet2 should swap details in the related cells.
And I SHOULD NOT HAVE TO COPY AND PASTE, from sheeet1 that has all customer data to sheet2 for invoice template,: just select the
Cells on sheet1 and automatically be copied on the invoice template on sheet2 in the specific cells to be ready to print.
That will be a real help, also for other templates I'm using with an excel sheet.
Thank You

in sheet2 Cell C4 put in a cell reference to whatever cell in Sheet1 Column A you are typing the name. Anything fancier will require the use of the formula INDIRECT() and/or code/script.

Wouldn't you better create a loop using vba?
